# Solving Third Maxwell Equation

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, differential-equations

Suppose I want to solve the third Maxwell equation:
$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B} = 0$$
The first assumption is that we could write the magnetic field as:
$$\mathbf{B} \equiv B(x,y,z) \equiv b(x)\beta(y)Z(z)$$
i.e. as a product of three functions, each of which depends on a single variable. This assumpion (or this kind of method), is not true in general, and it's not a general way to proceed, but we want to study what it'll come out.
Thence we have:
$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B} = \nabla\cdot\left(b(x)\beta(y)Z(z)\right) = \left(\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)\left(b(x)\beta(y)Z(z)\right) = 0$$
Simple algebra will take us to:
$$\displaystyle \beta(y)Z(z)\frac{\partial b(x)}{\partial x} + b(x)Z(z)\frac{\partial \beta(y)}{\partial y} + b(x)\beta(y)\frac{\partial Z(z)}{\partial z} = 0$$
Then the next step it to divide each member by $b(x)\beta(y)Z(z)$, so we get:
$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{b(x)}\frac{\partial b(x)}{\partial x} + \frac {1}{\beta(y)}\frac{\partial\beta(y)}{\partial y} + \frac{1}{Z(z)}\frac{\partial Z(z)}{\partial z} = 0$$
Using the differential equation notation $\left(i.e.\quad  b'(x) \equiv \displaystyle\frac{\partial b(x)}{\partial x}\right)$, we have a simpler writing:
$$\displaystyle\frac{b'(x)}{b(x)} + \frac{\beta'(y)}{\beta(y)} + \frac{Z'(z)}{Z(z)} = 0$$
Now we will make a second assumption: because each term of the equation above depends only on its variable and nothing else, we could hypotize this:
$$\begin{cases} 
\displaystyle\frac{b'(x)}{b(x)} = \lambda_1 \\\\ 
\displaystyle\frac{\beta'(y)}{\beta(y)} = \lambda_2 \\\\
\displaystyle\frac{Z'(z)}{Z(z)} = \lambda_3
\end{cases}
$$
With the necessary condition: $\boxed{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = 0}$. Solving each of those simple differential equations above, we get immediately:
$$
\begin{cases} 
b(x) = c_1e^{\lambda_1 x}\\
\beta(y) = c_2e^{\lambda_2 y}\\
Z(z) = c_3e^{\lambda_3 z}
\end{cases}
$$
Thence, the magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ could be wrote in the end as:
$$B(x,y,z) = b(x)\beta(y)Z(z) = c_1c_2c_3e^{\lambda_1 x}e^{\lambda_2 y}e^{\lambda_3 z} = Ce^{\lambda_1 x + \lambda_2y + \lambda_3z}$$
where $C = c_1c_2c_3$.
\\
Then having this expression of the magnetic field, to prove the relation $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B} = 0$ is quite simple. After little algebra we get:
$$C(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3)e^{\lambda_1x}e^{\lambda_2y}e^{\lambda_3z} = 0$$
As we told before, thanks to the (necessary) condition $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = 0$, the equation is satisfied.
\\
Naming now: $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = \Lambda \neq 0$, i.e. we assume that the (necessary) condition above, is unsatisfied. What we'll we obtain?\
Making the gradient of the magnetic field will bring us to the same expression before, but this time, we have $\Lambda \neq 0$. Thence:
$$C\Lambda e^{\lambda_1x}e^{\lambda_2y}e^{\lambda_3z} = 0$$
If we immediately simplify by $C\Lambda$, we have an exotic expression:
$$e^{\lambda_1x}e^{\lambda_2y}e^{\lambda_3z} = 0$$
We know that the exponential is never zero, unless we get the limit for the argument to $-\infty$
\
This is visible just putting the exponential in the hyperbolic sine and cosine form:
$$e^{\lambda_1x} = \sinh(\lambda_1x) + \cosh(\lambda_1x)$$
and so on for the other two terms.\
Analyzing this, we see that the expression is $0$ if and only if one of those term, like $\sinh(\lambda_1x) + \cosh(\lambda_1x)$, or $\sinh(\lambda_3x) + \cosh(\lambda_3x)$ is $0$. \
Analitically, the solution of the equation $\sinh(\lambda_1x) + \cosh(\lambda_1x) = 0$ is one and only, because it reduces to $\tanh(\lambda_1x) = -1$, and then $\lambda_1x = -\infty$.\\
In the end we could say that the form of the magnetic field found, is valid until is satisfied the condition $\Lambda = 0$, i.e. if and only if, because if $\Lambda \neq 0$, the equation becomes unphysical.
\\
Is this true, or is this totally wrong? and Why?

Comment: Your second equation is wrong. Magnetic field is a vector with three components, thus three functions of position. It cannot be replaced by a single function of position.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of $B$ doesn't make sense, because you make it a scalar field. Divergence is defined on vector fields, and the divergence at a point is equal to the flux exiting a small volume around that point. There's no "exiting" in a scalar field.  You need something like

$$B = X\mathbf{i} + Y\mathbf{j} + Z\mathbf{k}$$

And then the divergence simply gives you dX/dx + dY/dy + dZ/dz.